# Unselect all rows when deleting item from QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I have QTreeView with selection mode: SingleSelection ([selection modes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum)).

I want to delete selected item. Then [`rowsAboutToBeRemoved()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#rowsAboutToBeRemoved) function is called and neighbouring item is automatically selected as specified in [comment](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView20rowsAboutToBeRemovedERK11QModelIndexii): `// Ensure one selected item in single selection mode`.

How to avoid selection change?

1. How to make so that no items will be selected after deletion?
2. How to make so that parent of deleted item will be selected?

Comment: What about to call [`clearSelection()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clearSelection) after removing row ?

Comment: @ThibautB. It would be better to not execute body of `rowsAboutToBeRemoved()` at all, because behavior of my app depends on what selections are done. I am looking for a way to prevent such clever selection of neighbouring items.

Comment: So if you have to manage your own behavior after and before deleting, I suggest you to implement your own `QTreeView` and `QAbstractItemModel`, [`rowsAboutToBeRemoved()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#rowsAboutToBeRemoved) is a virtual protected slot, so you can do something.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid selecting an item AT ALL?  Or just trying to ensure that once the delete operation is complete, that the user is not presented with a TreeView that has an item selected?

Some actual code would help to evaluate the question.  The signals triggered make a difference.

Comment: @guitarpicva Actually I am trying to avoid emitting signal `currentChanged` from QTreeView which call my function each time user changes selection. This call with some item (which is not selected by user) breaks logic of my app.

Comment: I realize this is old, but commonly, I will explicitly select a new item to be selected BEFORE I delete the selected item.  In this way, it's deterministic and not left to defaults (if it matters to you).  QTreeView internal navigation is well documented.

Comment: I had a similar issue where removing the `currentIndex()` row triggers `currentChanged()` which scrolls the view. The solution there is to either not use single selection mode, or disable autoScroll

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
QTreeView view;
```

We can access the [`QItemSelectionModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html) instance and disable signals temporarily:

```
QItemSelectionModel *selectModel = view.selectionModel();
selectModel->blockSignals(true);
//set the selection
selectModel->blockSignals(false);
```

A quick nip into the source shows that Qt connects the `QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged()` signal to the view's `currentChanged()` slot, and this appears to be the source of your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud:

```
QTreeView view;
...
QItemSelection Modem *selectModel = view.selectionModel();
disconnect(selectModel, &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged,0, 0);
```

That's really sort of heavy handed, but as long as the QTreeView is tightly controlled by you, it might be worth a try.

I suppose the alternative is to roll your own implementation of the model so you can control the connections at creation time.

(NOTE: Thanks to @Jon Harper so that I could copy/paste source. ;) )